# Include a script into controller, factory, service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a script made of several methods. If I would like to include this script into a controller or a service in the way I could call these methods, which could be the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your javascript in angular controller, directive or service directly. For example, people use jquery in directive to work with DOM.

The Angular way is making your javascript be injectable into controller or service. The article [AngularJS providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) from developer guide is a good reference of recipes. For example, make your script a singleton by write an angular service.